# What is this type of web control/widget called?

Tags: jquery, plugins, widget

I'm looking to create a menu that is a hybrid of an accordion control and a fly-out menu, but I want to have it expand across the x axis instead of the y:

[alt text http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/1185/flyout.jpg](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/1185/flyout.jpg)

Is there a name for this widget? The name of a jQuery plugin would be even better.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're called sidebars. Example: [jQuery SideBar](http://sideroad.secret.jp/plugins/jQuerySideBar/).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question in any way.